# Whats the penalty for withdrawing from my Roth IRA when I day trade with it?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, day-trading, penalty

I have 12K in my Roth IRA. I use it to day trade. Now I want to take out the 12K what is my penalty? And do I get taxed on my trades when I buy and sell?

Comment: Are you talking about day trading within your IRA account?

Comment: @Acccumulation - it seems that was stated. While it was stated, it’s not part of the question, i.e. the question is regarding taxes.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica I feel that it implies some Gricean implicature.

Comment: The linked duplicate question addresses early withdrawal. The "day trading" is a red herring

Answer (score 6):

You are able to withdraw deposits tax-free. Any earnings are taxed, and a penalty may apply. The "day trading" has nothing to do with it.

Comment: What if I bought Tesla at $200 and then sold some at $400 and then re-bought again at 250 and sold again at 800? I profited twice.

Comment: This makes no difference. What matters is the total Roth deposits, and value when you take withdrawals, assuming you are pre-retirement age. Again, the transactions, how frequently, how many total, etc, are not relevant.

Comment: But isn't this how a non-ira stock trading account works? you pay tax on each trade that you made a profit on and not when you withdraw?

Comment: You're not asking about a non-ira account.